# Simple effects mixed ANOVA in R and Jamovi

Tags: r, anova, interaction, mixed

I calculated a mixed Anova with a within factor (3 levels) and a between factor (2 levels).  The between-within interaction is significant.
Now I want to look at the Simple Main Effects (for both factors).  What commands are there for the simple effects in R?  And how do I do a simple effects analysis in Jamovi?  I'd like to compare both R and Jamovi Analyses. Thank you very much.

So far I only have a R - command for the mixed anova ( ezAnova method).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.